# $\alpha$ is an arc of a circular helix or an arc of a circle if and only if both the curvature and the torsion of $\alpha$ are constant.

Tags: differential-geometry

Let $\alpha : I \rightarrow \mathbb{R}^3$ be a curve p.b.a.l. with $k(s) > 0$ for every
$s \in I$. Prove that $\alpha$ is an arc of a circular helix or an arc of a circle if and
only if both the curvature and the torsion of $\alpha$ are constant.

**My attempt**

For the first implication suppose that $ \alpha $ is an arc of a circular helix, then $ \alpha $ has the form $$\alpha(s) = (a\cos(s), a\sin(s),bs), \hspace{0.3cm} \text{where} \hspace{0.3cm} a>0,b \neq0$$ Then $$T(s) = (-a\sin(s), a\cos(s),b)$$ and
\begin{align*}
 T'(s) &= (-a\cos(s), -a\sin(s),0)\\
&= a (-\cos(s) , -\sin(s), 0)\\
&= k(s)N(s)
\end{align*}
Therefore $k(s) = a$ and $N(s) = (-\cos(s) , -\sin(s),0)$ for all $s \in I$. On the other hand, as $B(s) = T(s) \times N(s)$ then
\begin{align*}
 B(s) &= \det \begin{vmatrix} i&j&k\\ -a\cos(s) & a\cos(s)&b\\-\cos(s)&-\sin(s)&0 \end{vmatrix}\\
&=(b\sin(s), -b\cos(s), a)
\end{align*}
So $B'(s) = (b\cos(s), b\sin(s),0)$. Therefore
\begin{align*}
 \tau(s)&= B'(s) \cdot N(s)\\
&= (b\cos(s), b\sin(s), 0)\cdot (-\cos(s),-\sin(s),0)\\
&= -b\cos^{2}(s) -b\sin^{2}(s)\\
&=b
\end{align*}
This shows that $ \tau $ and $ k $ are constant if $ \alpha $ is the arc of a circular helix, how do you do when it is the arc of a circle? Another problem that I have is with the other implication, that is, how can I show that if the torsion and curvature are constant, then $ \alpha $ is the arc of a circular helix or an arc of a circle?

Comment: You need an arclength parametrization to do this computation. A circle is even easier. The converse is tricky if you do not know the Fundamental Theorem of Space Curves, but it can be done by solving a second-order differential equation for $N(s)$. If you search this site, you will find this question numerous times.

Comment: @TedShifrin I have searched this site several times for this question, but I have not found something to help me with this exercise, could you give me a link that will direct me?

Comment: Do you mean that the calculations I made in my post are incorrect?

Comment: Yes, the Frenet equations require an arclength parametrization. If you haven't studied this carefully, download my differential geometry text (free, linked in my profile) and it will help. There's also a hint about how to do the converse of this question.

Comment: @TedShifrin Right now I'm reading your book. Is very good. So if the curve $ \alpha $ in my exercise is parametrized by arc length, then my calculations in the post are correct?

Comment: But your specific parametrization is NOT by arclength. And your $T(s)$ is NOT a unit vector. So, no, not good.

Comment: @TedShifrin In my context the acronym p.b.a.l. translates parameterized by arc length.

Comment: I'm fully aware of that. What is the criterion for a parametrization you write down to be a pbal? You can't just put the letter $s$ and say you've done it!

Comment: @TedShifrin I have noticed that in my equation I must have $ a = 1 $ for it to be a p.b.a.l curve, is this correct?

Comment: No. Compute $\|\alpha'(s)\|$. (By the way, this example appears explicitly in the first few pages of my text!)